# Slicing a Dataframe using Timestamps

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I would like to pare down this dataframe to only store rows from dates between 1990-01-02 : 2010-06-30

```
df = pd.read_csv('___.txt',header=None,parse_dates=True, index_col={0},names="date open high low close date2 misc".split())
```

Given that my dates are considered Timestamps, something like this doesn't work:

```
w=df.ix[:,'1990-01-02':,:]

 or 

 df.index
```

Maybe a list comprehension would be better but I'm not sure of how to index the Timestamps is here. Your suggestions are appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: try ``df.ix['1990-01-02':'2010-06-30',:]``

Comment: @Jeff Is it possible to set the x-axis ticks to use the Timestamp? In matplotlib (under pylab mode) ax.set_xlim(['1/2/1990':'6/30/2010']) returns *integers* on the x-axis, not dates.

Comment: df.plot() should do it, see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html